# Query MySQL by alphanumeric & first 15

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need some help writing a MySQL query. It needs to look at all records, then sort them by first letter in an alpha-numeric range (Ex. numbers & A-C and then only return in $results the first 15 (in alphanumeric order)

Field to search is 'name'

Simple results showing all (I think 15 limit is right)- how do I modify it?

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT 15");
```

For Alpha Range:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT substr(theme, 1, 1) as Alphabet
  FROM gallery ORDER BY (CASE theme
  WHEN '1%' THEN 1
  WHEN '2%' THEN 2
  WHEN '3%' THEN 3
  WHEN 'A%' THEN 4
  WHEN 'B%' THEN 5
  ELSE -1
  END) LIMIT 15");
```

Getting: ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 15'

What am I doing wrong - trying to list 1's-3's, then A-B.

Update2:  In concert w/ above corrected query, I have a simple foreach to assign variables, then have variable echoes in content:

```
$x = 0
foreach ($results as $row) {
  $x++;
  if ($x == 1) {  // first in query
    $t1 = $row['theme'];
    $d1 = $row['developer'];
    $th1 = $row['thumb'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Nothing is showing, is there something different I have to do in assigning variables?

Update 3: Do you mean this?  Still isn't showing.

```
$x = 0
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  $x++;
  if ($x == 1) {  // first in query
    $t1 = $row['theme'];
    $d1 = $row['developer'];
    $th1 = $row['thumb'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Echo Ex. in body:

```
<img src="<?php echo($th1); ?>" alt="<?php echo($t1); ?>" />
<span><p class="hname"><?php echo($t1); ?></p>
<p class="hdev"><?php echo($d1); ?></p></span>
```

Comment: I forgot to add 'END" to my original query. See update.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments, edit your post and add that code there.

Comment: Ok, moved code into post.

Comment: Any time that you have a new question based on another post you should make a new question with a link back to that post. Having said that (don't do it now) it should be `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {...`

Comment: See Update3 question.  Still doesn't show.

Comment: Placed body echo example in question above

Comment: Which PHP functions are you using for interacting with the database? I notice that you are connecting to a class method `DB::query`. Does that class have a method for iterating through rows?

Comment: I'm using MeekroDB:  http://www.meekro.com/quickstart.php  Not sure how to translate to their method.

Comment: We're starting to venture off into new territory that is not related to the original question. Can you create a new question about not being able to see the results (with all of the proper code, of course)?

Comment: Ok, posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999897/query-mysql-alphanumeric-w-limit-using-meekrodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this -

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM Mytable ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 15");
```

You probably shouldn't have a column named 'name' though. Those kinds of generic words are often reserved by the systems that you're using.

If you need something more specialized, like limiting to a certain portion of the alphabet, your queries start to become much more complex.

```
SELECT substr(name, 1, 1) as Alphabet
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY (CASE name
    WHEN 'D%'    THEN 1
    WHEN 'E%'    THEN 2
    WHEN 'F%'    THEN 3
    ELSE -1
    END
)
LIMIT 15
```

Doing the syntax right off the top of my head, you will have to test for your situation.

Comment: How do I change it if the alpha range is changed to D-F ?

Comment: When it starts to become specialized the queries much more complex. I have added an example in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, Jay, I don't see the additional example in your answer ;)

Comment: It's there now. What are you trying to accomplish with your queries?

Comment: The DEF one, is similar to the first, limit queries to field starting w/ those letters & then limit further to first 15 - obviously would have to add the DESC LIMIT 15 to the end of your specialized query - thanks for the help.

Comment: Quick followup, what if I need to list numbers first, then D-F ?  And should I add DESC before LIMIT ?

Comment: You really don't need DESC here because the order is enforced by the THEN's. You can put it there, it won't hurt. If you want numbers first you can do a couple of things a.) add to the WHEN statements or 2.) re-think your filtering logic.