# Query MySQL alphanumeric w/ Limit using MeekroDB

Tags: php, mysql, meekro

I'm trying to sort by certain alphanumeric range 1-3 & A-B for first 15 matches, but am getting nothing in output.  Using [MeekroDB](http://meekro.com/quickstart.php).   Not sure how to translate what I have here to their method.

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT substr(theme, 1, 1) as Alphabet
FROM gallery ORDER BY (CASE theme
  WHEN '1%' THEN 1
  WHEN '2%' THEN 2
  WHEN '3%' THEN 3
  WHEN 'A%' THEN 4
  WHEN 'B%' THEN 5
  ELSE -1
END) LIMIT 15"); 

$x = 0
foreach ($results as $row) {
  $x++;
  if ($x == 1) {  // first in query
    $t1 = $row['theme'];
    $d1 = $row['developer'];
    $th1 = $row['thumb'];
    $thlg1 = $row['thumb_lg'];
  }
  ...
}
```

Echo example in body:

```
<img src="<?php echo($th1); ?>" data-retina="<?php echo($thlg1); ?>" alt="<?php echo($t1); ?>" />
<span><p class="hname"><?php echo($t1); ?></p>
<p class="hdev"><?php echo($d1); ?></p></span>
```

Update2:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT substr(theme, 1, 1) as Alphabet, theme, developer, thumb, thumb_lg
FROM gallery ORDER BY (CASE
  WHEN theme LIKE '1%' THEN 1
  WHEN theme LIKE '2%' THEN 2
  WHEN theme LIKE '3%' THEN 3
  WHEN theme LIKE 'A%' THEN 4
  WHEN theme LIKE 'B%' THEN 5
  ELSE -1
END) LIMIT 15");
```

Update3:

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT substr(theme, 1, 1) as Alphabet, theme, developer, thumb, thumb_lg FROM gallery
  ORDER BY (CASE Alphabet
    WHEN '1' THEN 1
    WHEN '2' THEN 2
    WHEN '3' THEN 3  
    WHEN 'A' THEN 4
    WHEN 'B' THEN 5
    ELSE 6
  END)
  LIMIT 15");
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `LIKE` to perform a pattern match? Your CASE expression is doing exact matches.

Comment: Does the query itself produce results when run against the database? echo $x when you start it to make sure that there is a row to echo.

Comment: When I echo $results, get word Array.

Comment: That's what you get when you try to echo an array in PHP. Use `var_dump()` to see the contents.

Comment: `if ($x == 1)` is limiting your result to one row.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I suspect the `...` includes cases for other values of `$x`.

Comment: Your query only returns one column, `Alphabet`. There's no `theme`, `developer`, or `thumb`.

Comment: I suspect that you may be right @Barmar, but I'd sure remove it for testing.

Comment: Good eye @Barmar! I have been looking at this with the OP and I totally brain-farted! *facepalm*

Comment: Here's my test page:  http://www.partiproductions.com/vault_test/1-a-b.php  Ran var_dump($results)  Yes, x=1 is just for 1st match, I have 14 more, but just showing one for simplicity ;)  So what do I need to do?

Comment: Add the columns to the query that @Barmar spotted as missing. `SELECT substr(theme, 1, 1) as Alphabet, theme, developer, thumb FROM...`

Comment: You can see on the test page, var_dump is producing weird results. Is it thinking Alphabet is one of my fields, as it's not.  I'm also pulling in a thumb_lg  FYI: first row id= 1, theme=Bella, developer=2bitoperation & thumb=resources/Thumbs/bella-v.jpg, & thumb_lg=(blank at the moment)

Comment: Wait, I just updated code to use foreach (was using a while loop) & now, at least stuff is coming through.   BUT - it's not in the alphanumeric order it should be in.  There's a theme that starts w/ '3' & others that start w/ 'a' that should be listed first.

Comment: @Barmar  Guys, still not getting correct Case sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause should be:

```
ORDER BY CASE Alphabet
    WHEN '1' THEN 1
    WHEN '2' THEN 2
    WHEN '3' THEN 3
    WHEN 'A' THEN 4
    WHEN 'B' THEN 5
    ELSE 6
END, theme
```

Your code is doing exact matches on the whole theme, '1%' should have been matched using `LIKE`.  My version just uses the first character, which you already extracted into `Alphabet`.

Another way to write this is:

```
ORDER BY IF(LOCATE(Alphabet, "123AB"), 0, 1), theme
```

This works because the order of your first characters matches the normal lexicographic order.

Comment: Updated code $results above, but still getting weird results.

Comment: Please don't change the question to match the answer. How is someone supposed to know what the problem was that I fixed?

Comment: How are the results weird? This should show all the themes that don't begin with `1-3` or `A-B` first, then the ones with these prefixes.

Comment: The results should show themes alphanumerically that do begin w/ a number/letter of 1,2,3,A & B  (In that order)  Thus, Ex:  3-Dimensional should be shown first, then aRRaNGe, Artist2, etc...

Comment: Then you should make the `ELSE` value higher than all the others, not lower.

Comment: Ok, It's getting close, see update3 code above.  Listings w/in each letter set aren't in alphabetical order, Ex, Currently: 3-Dimensional, AutoCue, aRRaNGe, AutoCue Arrows, etc...  Can we get it to look at the entire theme name to determine the order?